# Stack view child changes width when hidden

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a stack view that stretches the full width of the device. Inside this stack view, I have another stack view with a collection view. So it looks like this:

```
- Stack view
-- Stack view 
--- Collection view
```

Straightforward enough.

However, when I set the second stack view to hidden, the width of the stack view becomes 112 for whatever reason. I need it to stay as the full width of the device, as I use the width of this stack view in my code to do further calculations.

Why is the width changing of the second stack view when I hide it, and how can I hide it but keep the width the full width of the device?

Comment: That depends on how it is set up. Are you using Storyboards or are you setting things up programmatically?

Comment: Either way, you'll want to take a look at the constraints that are getting set.

Comment: @Jake I'm using storyboards

Comment: Take a look at the constraints on each view.

Comment: The outermost stack view should have constraints set to the parent view bounds, but not to its children

Answer (score 0):

You should set top of stackview layout, set it width same as his parent view, or left/right align to his parent view.